# Customize - Ola Hallengren script

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

Trying to incorporate Date wise folder in the script. Following is the original code

```
  INSERT INTO @CurrentDirectories (ID, DirectoryPath, Mirror, DirectoryNumber, CreateCompleted, CleanupCompleted)
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID), DirectoryPath + CASE WHEN RIGHT(DirectoryPath,1) = '\' THEN '' ELSE '\' END + CASE WHEN @CurrentAvailabilityGroup IS NOT NULL THEN @Cluster + '$' + @CurrentAvailabilityGroup ELSE REPLACE(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('servername') AS nvarchar(max)),'\','$') END + '\' + @CurrentDatabaseNameFS + '\' + UPPER(@CurrentBackupType) + CASE WHEN @ReadWriteFileGroups = 'Y' THEN '_PARTIAL' ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN @CopyOnly = 'Y' THEN '_COPY_ONLY' ELSE '' END, Mirror, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Mirror ORDER BY ID ASC), 0, 0
      FROM @Directories
      ORDER BY ID ASC
```

I added `'\' + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101), '/', '') +'\' +` to the above code to have folders by date

```
INSERT INTO @CurrentDirectories (ID, DirectoryPath, Mirror, DirectoryNumber, CreateCompleted, CleanupCompleted)
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID), DirectoryPath + CASE WHEN RIGHT(DirectoryPath,1) = '\' THEN '' ELSE '\' END + '\' + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101), '/', '') +'\' + CASE WHEN @CurrentAvailabilityGroup IS NOT NULL THEN @Cluster + '$' + @CurrentAvailabilityGroup ELSE REPLACE(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('servername') AS nvarchar(max)),'\','$') END + '\' + @CurrentDatabaseNameFS + '\' + UPPER(@CurrentBackupType) + CASE WHEN @ReadWriteFileGroups = 'Y' THEN '_PARTIAL' ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN @CopyOnly = 'Y' THEN '_COPY_ONLY' ELSE '' END, Mirror, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Mirror ORDER BY ID ASC), 0, 0
      FROM @Directories
      ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Now after modifying the code with the above syntax , I could see the DateFolder gets created but somehow backup is not happening. See the error below

> DECLARE @ReturnCode int EXECUTE @ReturnCode =
>   [master].dbo.xp_create_subdir
>   N'N:\Test\FullUserDBBackups\10152017\CLU-DBSQL-TEST$DB2012_TEST\AX_TEST\FULL_COPY_ONLY'
>   IF @ReturnCode <> 0 RAISERROR('Error creating directory.', 16, 1)
>
> BACKUP DATABASE [] TO DISK =
>   N'N:\Test\FullUserDBBackups\10152017\CLU-DBSQL-TEST$AX2012_PROD\AX_TEST\FULL_COPY_ONLYCLU-DBSQL-TESTAX2012_TEST_AX_TEST_FULL_COPY_ONLY_20171015_042734.bak'
>   WITH CHECKSUM, COMPRESSION, COPY_ONLY

Comment: The error is on line 17.